# Memory debugging problem

Tags: iphone

I am launching my app in the instruments to detect leaked objects and debug memory.

When I launch it, I have many leaks. I would like to know

1. How much ( in Kbyte) have I leaked object?
2. What is the total size of the objects leaked in my app?

Should I have 0 byte leaked object when I launch instruments? ( to be validate per apple)

Another question: Do you see any memory leak in this code :

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:......alpha:1.0];
```

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tintColor code does not leak.  You don't have to have 0 bytes leaked for Apple to accept your app.  You should strive for that though.

The leaks instrument will tell you all the information you need to know.